# How can I run mods with 1.8.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have minecraft 1.8, 1.8.1 and 1.8.3 and forge on my computer.  we have installed mods for 1.8, but my son (8) wants to make a hot air balloon that flies, and I can only find a mod for this (or can he build one without a mod?) in 1.8.1, but forge won't work with 1.8.1.  How do I get the mods to install for the 1.8.1 version? do you need something other than forge to use for 1.8.1 mods?

Answer (score 5):

Forge (the mod platform needed for most mods) for 1.8 is still in beta, but you **CAN** download it.

The problem is most mods have not updated to 1.8.

Archimedes Ships is the mod you are looking for; it lets you create airships and boats, but it too is not updated to 1.8. If you'd like to follow the development of Archimedes Ships, watch this forum post:
http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1289952-archimedes-ships-v1-7-banking-ships

When it does update to 1.8, you can download Forge for 1.8 from here:
http://files.minecraftforge.net/
You'll probably want the '**1.8-Recommended  Installer-Win**' build.

You can also backdate to 1.7 and use the Archimedes Ships 1.7 versions.